# using reduce to sum values in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, functional-programming

lets say I have a list of dictionaries

```
parents = [
{'Name': 'Peter', 'Kids': 2},
{'Name': 'Mary', 'Kids': 1},
{'Name': 'Lia', 'Kids': 3}
]
```

I am using map to change the values for those that have more than 2 kids to 1 by using map. Next, I am trying to use reduce to sum the total number of kids.

I have managed to get the filter and map to work but I am stuck at the reduce part, does anyone have any suggestions?

This is what I have for now

```
total = reduce(lambda x, y: x+y["Kids"], map(lambda x: x["Kids"]-2, filter(lambda x:x["Kids"] > 2, parents)))
```

However, it returns me 1.

Comment: You don't set zero at first. your try gets two elements from `dict`.

Comment: Your code does not work for me, you need to change `> 3` in the filter to`> 2`

Comment: You get 1, because there is only one greater than 2, Lia

Comment: @rkive See my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) as follows:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import add


filtered = filter(lambda x: x["Kids"] >= 2, parents)
edited = map(lambda _: 1, filtered)
res = reduce(add, edited)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
2
```

In one-line:

```
total = reduce(add, map(lambda _: 1, filter(lambda x: x["Kids"] >= 2, parents)))
print(total)
```

If you wan to avoid importing add do (full example):

```
add = lambda x, y : x + y
filtered = filter(lambda x: x["Kids"] >= 2, parents)
edited = map(lambda _: 1, filtered)
res = reduce(add, edited)
print(res)
```

Note that all the examples above I used `>=` greater than or equal.

Comment: I am trying to use only reduce() in this situation, is there a way to do that?

Comment: @rkive See the update

Comment: How can I include the newList in my reduce as well?

Comment: @rkive See the updaate